# AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate not recognizing implemented methods Swift 3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, migration, swift2

So long story short, I'm implementing AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate but the XCode isn't recognizing the required methods.

Since I started to migrate my code to Swift 3, my class that implement this delegate keep giving a error saying

```
Type 'VideoViewController' does not conform to protocol 'AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate'
```

I know that I only need to implement this method

```
public func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAt outputFileURL: URL!, fromConnections connections: [Any]!, error: Error!)
```

so, what I have done until now:

- Cleaned the project ( didn't work )
- Cleaned the build folder ( didn't work )
- Created a new project that implemented this delegate ( this worked )
- Commented all others functions that doesn't belong to this delegate ( didn't work )
- Created a new ViewController inside my project that only implemented this delegate ( didn't work )
- Closed XCode to be sure that wasn't a cache problem ( didn't work =/ )
- Tried to run the project in a older version of XCode

Some times XCode suggest a fix-it to implement the "missing" method

```
    /*!
 @method captureOutput:didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:fromConnections:error:
 @abstract
 Informs the delegate when all pending data has been written to an output file.

 @param captureOutput
 The capture file output that has finished writing the file.
 @param fileURL
 The file URL of the file that has been written.
 @param connections
 An array of AVCaptureConnection objects attached to the file output that provided the data that was written to the file.
 @param error
 An error describing what caused the file to stop recording, or nil if there was no error.

 @discussion
 This method is called when the file output has finished writing all data to a file whose recording was stopped, either because startRecordingToOutputFileURL:recordingDelegate: or stopRecording were called, or because an error, described by the error parameter, occurred (if no error occurred, the error parameter will be nil). This method will always be called for each recording request, even if no data is successfully written to the file.

 Clients should not assume that this method will be called on a specific thread.

 Delegates are required to implement this method.
 */
@available(iOS 4.0, *)
public func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAt outputFileURL: URL!, fromConnections connections: [Any]!, error: Error!) {

}
```

but after this, XCode says that the method is duplicated and still say that the class doesn't implement the required methods

anyone knows how why this is happening and how to solve it?

thanks everybody

EDIT 1

this is the class that I created inside my project to test and happens the same error

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

class VVC : UIViewController, AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate {
/*!
 @method captureOutput:didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:fromConnections:error:
 @abstract
 Informs the delegate when all pending data has been written to an output file.

 @param captureOutput
 The capture file output that has finished writing the file.
 @param fileURL
 The file URL of the file that has been written.
 @param connections
 An array of AVCaptureConnection objects attached to the file output that provided the data that was written to the file.
 @param error
 An error describing what caused the file to stop recording, or nil if there was no error.

 @discussion
 This method is called when the file output has finished writing all data to a file whose recording was stopped, either because startRecordingToOutputFileURL:recordingDelegate: or stopRecording were called, or because an error, described by the error parameter, occurred (if no error occurred, the error parameter will be nil). This method will always be called for each recording request, even if no data is successfully written to the file.

 Clients should not assume that this method will be called on a specific thread.

 Delegates are required to implement this method.
 */
@available(iOS 4.0, *)
func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAt outputFileURL: URL!, fromConnections connections: [Any]!, error: Error!) {

}
}
```

Comment: Show the code relevant for assigning the delegate.

Comment: this is the head of my class 'class VideoViewController: PublishViewController, AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate'

Comment: Don't you need a `import UIKit` too?

Comment: Not necessarily but I add only to make sure... keep showing the same error

Comment: Since you already went through cleaning project, try cleaning XCode Derived Data

Comment: Just cleaned the XCode Derived Data... didn't work.
I think it's something related with settings because when I created a new project worked like a charm, but on my project doesn't work. I just didn't find any clue of what it could be.

Comment: Check "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" on target level.

Comment: I left only the AVFoundation and the pod there and didn't work. I'm gonna test the pods now. Anyother suggestion? Tks for the help @Kamil.S

Comment: Close your workspace, do 
`pod deintegrate`
`pod cache clean --all`
`pod install`
Open workspace , do a clean and then try triggering the build.

Comment: so, didn't work neither =/

Comment: @FilipeFaria i'm also facing this issue, did you get the solution ?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the cause of your problem, but I had this same issue and it was due to a `Candidate has non matching type` error.

I had created a new type named `Error` who's full namespaces name would be `[Namespace].Error` which conflicted with Swift's `Error` type.

When implementing `AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate` XCode will add the protocol function signatures and the `didFinishRecordingTo` function has an `Error` type.  I had to change this to be Swift's version of the type `Swift.Error`

```
func fileOutput(
    _ output: AVCaptureFileOutput,
    didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL,
    from connections: [AVCaptureConnection],
    error: Swift.Error?
) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: oh yeah! this one should be accepted! I also had to replace just `Error` with `Swift.Error`.

Comment: Could someone accept this as the correct answer? This is a perfect solution! Thanks a lot!